# getSupportFragmentManager failing in compatibility library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I am displaying a dialog fragment in activity, tried using show() and add() methods. The code is given below

```
HelpDialogFragment hdf = HelpDialogFragment.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(hdf, "dialog");
ft.commit(); #crash here
```

I get IllegalStateException error sometimes from the above code, The crash log is given below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1329)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:548)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:532)
at com.delight.activities.HomeActivity.showHelp(HomeActivity.java:311)
```

Line no. 311 in HomeActivity.java is `ft.commit()` mentioned in the code above. My activity extends FragmentActivity from compatibility library(which is update to date). The same crash occurs if i use `show()` method.

```
HelpDialogFragment hdf = HelpDialogFragment.newInstance();
hdf.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");  #same crash here
```

So i came to a conclusion that `getSupportFragmentManager()` is causing me the problems, what i don't understand is that , in what part of the code am I using the activity that has been destroyed, as far as i understand `getSupportFragmentManager()` should return me the manager for the activity that is present.

I need some help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Can you post your activity code?

Comment: Just a blind shot, have you called `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` as a first statement in your `Activity`'s `onCreate()`?

Answer (score 0):

see for a dialog fragment u only need to call dialogfrag.show(Fmanager,tag);
Adding it via transaction gives an exception

Answer (score 0):

Use getFragmentManager instead of getSupportFragmentManager

```
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "submitting"); // The second parameter doesn't really matter.
```

If that doesn't work extend DialogFragment to do it. The key is to use your Activity when building dialog instead of using support library.

```
dialog = new AlertDialogFragment(title, message);
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "submitting");
```

AlertDialogFragment:

```
    public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
        static final String TAG_MSG = "message";

        public AlertDialogFragment(){

        }

        public AlertDialogFragment(String title, String message) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString(TAG_TITLE, title);
            b.putString(TAG_MSG, message);

            setArguments(b);
        }

        public AlertDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
            AlertDialogFragment frag = new AlertDialogFragment();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString(TAG_TITLE, title);
            b.putString(TAG_MSG, message);

            frag.setArguments(b);
            return frag;
        }

        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            String title = getArguments().getString(TAG_TITLE);
            String message = getArguments().getString(TAG_MSG);
                // Use getActivity()!
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle(title)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Dialog cancel");
                        }
                    }).create();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cancel Dialog");
            super.onCancel(dialog);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Dismiss Dialog");
            super.onDismiss(dialog);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can't use getFragmentManager() in activity,i think it can only be used in fragments.

Comment: @YashwanthKumar You use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in (support) `FragmentActivity` and `getFragmentManager()` in (standard) `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should extend FragmentActivity not Activity. This solved the problem for me